# Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng()

Tags: php, gd

Windows server 2008 R2
IIS
PHP 5.6.18

phpinfo GD section - Yes it is installed

GD Support enabled 
GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible) 
FreeType Support enabled 
FreeType Linkage with freetype 
FreeType Version 2.6.2 
GIF Read Support enabled 
GIF Create Support enabled 
JPEG Support enabled 
libJPEG Version 9 compatible 
PNG Support enabled 
libPNG Version 1.5.26 
WBMP Support enabled 
XPM Support enabled 
libXpm Version 30411 
XBM Support enabled 
WebP Support enabled

IUSR and other service accounts have rights to gd2.dll
Checked that the php.ini is correct one.

Can anyone think of why I get the error. It's driving me mad.

Comment: Are you running phpinfo through the web server or through cli? Are you running the script the same way? It's possible to have a separate php.ini for web vs cli.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - Server API CGI/FastCGI web page is served over this too. phpinfo was in the same page as the error. Error remains the smae if I remove the phpinfo call.

Comment: You can run `php --ini` from the CLI to see what configuration files are being loaded and any additional configurations.

Comment: It's loading the same one I thought it was and nothing else

Comment: So, it turns out to be this...(after a week of banging my head against the wall)...
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('path/to/file');
had to be
$im=imagecreatefromjpeg('path/to/file');
Remove the spaces and it works. No idea why, but there you go.